# How to do lookbehind and lookforward at the same time around a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

The input is this:

```
*Word. Word.* Word word. *…*

"…" Word word. "…"

"…" word. "…"
```

The following is matching the empty space on the right side of a sentence.

```
(?<=["*]*[A-Z].+?\.["*]*)\s
```

If I want to match the empty space on the left side, I have to do this:

```
\s(?=["*]*[A-Z].+?\.["*]*)
```

The output should be this (the `[]` symbolize the matches):

```
*Word.[]Word.*[]Word word.[]*…*

"…"[]Woad word.[]"…"

"…" word.[]"…"
```

How to modify this regex so it matches the empty spaces on both sides of a sentence at the same time?

https://regexr.com/5tddc

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing us the _exact_ input along with the output you expect.

Comment: You can probably use: `/(?<!\w)[ \t]|[ \t](?!\w)/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the examples shown, you may be able to use this regex with look arounds to match spaces:

```sh
(?<=\.\*?) |(?<!\w) (?=[A-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p5oVTG/3/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\.\*?)` : Match a space if that is preceded by a dot and optional `*`
- `|`: OR
- `(?<!\w) (?=[A-Z])`: Match a space that must be followed by an uppercase letter and must not be preceded by a word character

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, why did you include tabs in the regex? I think I've never seen sentences  separated by tab characters.

Comment: Good point. I just kept it because you used `\s` which matches space, tab and line break. Have removed it now

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention in my example. Sometimes there's `"…" word.` and that whole thing is a sentence.

Comment: ok so `"…" Word word.` is one sentence? If yes then your expected output should also be fixed.

Comment: `"…" Word word` are two sentences because the first `Word` is capitalized. (I fixed the question.)

Comment: ok can you try: `(?<=\.\*?) |(?<!\w) (?=[A-Z])` ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can match a non word boundary and assert either an uppercase char A-Z or one of `"` `*` at the right.

```
\B[ ](?=[A-Z"*])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\B` A position where `\b` does not match
- `[ ]` Match a space (The brackets are for clarity only)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is

  - `[A-Z"*]` Match one of A-Z or `"` or `*`
- `)` Close lookahead

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WXnPPK/1)